# Solving error for the good beginning of the day

Tags: r, regression, panel

Let's consider data following

```
library(plm)
library(pglm)
data("EmplUK", package="plm")
```

I will add new column with 0 and 1 randomly placed. After that I want to perform logit random effects model.

```
df1<-EmplUK
#adding 0's and 1's
df1<-cbind(df1,'binary'=sample(0:1,1031,replace=T))
#Performing logit regression 
pglm(binary~output+wage, data=df1, family=quasibinomial(link='logit'), start = NULL, model = 'random')
```

And the following problem occurs :

```
Error in maxRoutine(fn = logLik, grad = grad, hess = hess, start = start,  : 
  argument "start" is missing, with no default
```

I'm not sure exactly what's the reason, I've read about this error and it seems that there are some problems when you trying to estimate 'within' model, but I get this error for every model type. Could you please give me a hand pointing out reason of this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the quasibinomial family is setup in this function. Inside `pglm` there is a function `pglm:::starting.values` that looks for specific families:

```
"binomial"
"ordinal"
"poisson"
"negbin"
"gaussian"
"tobit"
```

Negative binomial allows for modelling of the variance so that may suit your needs else `binomial(link='logit')` works ok if there's no evidence of overdispersion.

edit: happy to be corrected on this, I haven't worked with this package before :)

Comment: Thank you! I picked binomial and know it's working :D